# Java8 reindexing a map "groupingBy" count in parallel stalls

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I need to index a previously built map by sub-item count.

When I run the following code it stalls. Remove the `.parallel()` instruction and it runs fine.

What am I missing?

```
Map<String, List<String>> dataById = 
    Files.lines(...).parallel()
      .groupingBy(l->l.substring(0,l.indexof(' ')));
Map<Integer, List<String>> idsByCnt = dataById.entrySet().stream().parallel()
    // collect
    .collect(
            //
            groupingBy(
                    // grouping key is number data elements
                    e -> e.getValue().size(),
                    // value is the id
                    mapping(Entry::getKey, toList())));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it stalls"? I just tested with dummy values and it worked fine. Could you post a reproducing example?

Comment: @Tunaki every Thread is waiting or locked. if I comment out the  `.parallel()` this part of my code executes within 100ms

Comment: @Cerber Could it be that some other code is using the common FJ pool too and you have a thread starvation scenario?

Comment: It would be helpful to know which actual `Map` type `dataById` has, which size and how many groups we have to expect (though we can already guess that it’s rather a small number of groups). Of course, a [mcve] would be even better.

Comment: What's your input `dataById` Map implementation?

Comment: dataById is created by collecting all the lines from a file and grouping them by the first word of the line. (`Files.lines(...).parallel().groupingBy(...)`). As said below, I'm unable to create a working example of this behaviour ... I'll close this question. Just for the sake of completeness, this code is in a static initializer of a deepely nested class that is called by other parallel streams in specific case. This code helps caching values and show duplicates as warning (thus my new idByCnt)

Answer (score 1):

try `groupingByConcurrent` instead.  Otherwise the Map it uses is single threaded.

Comment: done, doesn't work either

Comment: @Cerber Can you provide a test where we can reproduce the problem ourselves as "doesn't work" is not helpful?

Comment: I've worked a lot to reproduce it in a test case but can't find a way to make it fail. The problem is probably more complex than this sole line. Thanks for pointing me out `groupingByConcurrent` anyway

Comment: @Cerber if you update HashMap concurrently, it can get into a state where it goes into an infinite loop.  This would explain the behavior you saw.

Comment: Nop, I've already learned this pitfall (the hard way) years ago. I've updated the code above to show a clearer picture of dataById creation